# jqGrid minimise column and append ... if some content hidden

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, outlook

With regards to [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Before I go off creating some custom code, is there any jqGrid experts out there who has done this - append '...' if user minimise a column and there is some hidden content... similar to what can be done in Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at this: http://www.bramstein.com/projects/text-overflow/ which is a work-around just for Firefox, but it is producing some funky results within the jqGrid, esp. when set to auto. Might be feasible just to leave out FF until they include the text-overflow property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow) to avoid adding a whole chunk of javascript to the solution (which will no doubt be out-dated in the near future and is pretty performance intensive for a grid even for FF)

For IE6 to IE8, Safari and Chrome, just use CSS

```
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
text-overflow:ellipsis;p
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand you correct, but it seems to me that you want to have trimming of the cell text correspond to [punctuation-trim](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-text-20101005/#punctuation-trim0) CSS3 style which currently not supported in any web browsers. Of course you can try to simulate the behavior, but it will be not easy and is it really required? I recommend you to be more pragmatical and to use just the features existing "out-of-the-box". The dotted trimming is not such feature.

Comment: Will be easy to understand if you just adjust the columns in Outlook so that the width is less than the content, the content will append "..." to indicate that there is hidden stuff. It is a nice to have... and yes, of course I know it is not easy! I don't think it is possible with any CSS property. This needs to be a javascript solution. I will take this as a 'Not possible/Have not been done before' answer, coming from Oleg... and try to conjure up a new javascript solution.

Comment: @Brandon: I know that such effect is easy to implement under Windows one can for example use [DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498(VS.85).aspx) with `DT_END_ELLIPSIS` as the format option. The API exist since very long time, but I don't know a simple way how to implement the same behavior in CSS or JavaScript. Probably one have to place the cell contain inside of `<span>` element to be able to calculate the width in pixel. Then one should try to cut the text from the cell so that together with "..." the text width will be less then the cell width. Something like this...

Comment: I'll have a look at this plugin and see if I can Mod it. -
http://www.adamcoulombe.info/lab/jquery/width-truncate/

Comment: This is even better - http://www.bramstein.com/projects/text-overflow/jquery.text-overflow.js

Comment: @Brandon: At the first look it seems to do almost the same what I imagine, but the usage the steps of the text cutting starting from 1 and then i++ seems me very slow. One should search the optimal step dividing the width by 2. Nevertheless it seems good starting point for the first tests. The code you can optimize if needed. I did't wrote before, but the truncating the text you should use only for the columns used `formatter` producing simple text instead of more complex HTML fragments.

Comment: @Brandon: If you receive a demo with some from plugins it would be interesting for me to see it. You can append you question with the url to the demo.

Comment: @Oleg thanks bro, sorry I had to untick your answer, but I will post the solution once fully tested.

Comment: Kick myself for saying it's not possible in CSS. Have to love CSS!